# How do you maintain the temporary images for image previews in an HTML form

Tags: html, ajax

To get backwards compatibility, it seems like you have to upload an image in order to preview it with AJAX. I've found various plugins which do this quite effectively like Uploadify, UploadSWF and the jQuery file upload plugin from http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ (this last one uses an HTML5 canvas if supported so the file doesn't have to actually be uploaded if HTML5 is supported).

It seems to me that when the form actually gets submitted you then have to copy the relevant file to a more permanent location and get rid of the other temporary files. What do people do for this? Do you just run a cronjob or something? I haven't seen anyone talking about this. Is there some more clever way of maintaining the temporary previews?

Comment: What "the other temporary files"? The image is usually saved in its destination folder directly.

Comment: oh, but what if the user just leaves the page and doesn't want to save. Or what if there is already a file that is being updated (like a profile picture). You can't just overwrite that until the user definitely wants to submit changes

Comment: You should have an associated DB record for the upload. In there set the status. Once in a while run a cron job to kill all the non-active records/images. No temporary storage required.

Comment: ok, so you do need to run a cron job. 
Also, unless your db is storing multiple images in the table, you'd surely need to keep a separate table with the ones being used for the preview. Otherwise you're overwriting the one in the table before a submit. I agree that my original thought of saving the file itself in a separate location is pointless - just go directly to where you want it.

Comment: "preview" is a state of a column in a record, it doesn't need to be in a separate table.

Comment: Let me check I understand here. In the case of a user profile picture you would have a table with user_name, password and a picture_id, and then a separate table for profile pictures with user_id, picture_id, picture_path creation_date and preview_state. When the form is submitted the new picture_id gets put in the user table and all others records for that user can be deleted. You do still have an extra table though. I can't see that you could have just a user table with a picture_path field and a preview column.